# How to Reference to ObjectID Array in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema, and I want to do populate on this.

```
categories: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Category', default: undefined },
```

However, the schema that I have defined is an Array through type, and the "ref" keyword is external, so populate does not work.

The reason I don't use the format of [{type ...}] is because basically I don't want to create the field itself.

Answer (score 0):

in the schema it should be an array of `ObjectIds`, like this

```
categories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', default: undefined }],
```

hope it helps